# Resetting the value of a JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jcombobox

I have a `JComboBox` which contains some employee ID numbers (which are integer values).

I want to set 'Select employee' to the JComboBox as a default value. As this value is in string format its throwing me an exception like "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Select Employee"".
How do I do this?

My code is:

```
public void clear()
 {
    cmb_emp_id.setSelectedItem("Select Employee");
    txt_emp_name.setText("");
    txt_department.setText("");
    txt_designation.setText("");
    joining_date.setDate(new Date());
    resign_date.setDate(new Date());
    txt_description.setText("");
 }
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Which of those lines throw `NumberFormatException`?

Comment: cmb_emp_id.setSelectedItem("Select Employee");
this line is throwing exception..

Comment: I recommend you to do `setSelectedIndex(0)` to avoid writing that string constant in two places in the code and follow the DRY principle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're after, especially since you're talking about a number format exception.

However, to reset a `JComboBox` to it's original selection, you simply do

```
cmb_emp_id.setSelectedIndex(0);
```

Comment: Ahh... man, I found 4 swing questions, which I was able to answer, and while I was answering I see your answer coming up. How come you be so fast?

Comment: Hehe... by 99k, you'll be much faster than me ;-)

Comment: @Harshali I guess you are having changeListener on your combo box, which tries to parse the selected item to number and when you select this default item it fails to parse.

Comment: I bet you have some listener that validates the input or something. As soon as the input changes to `"Select Employee"`, the validator tries to interpret it as an integer and chokes. You'll have to work around this somehow, for instance by interpreting `"Select Employee"` as `-1` or something. You you post more of the code, I might be able to help.

Comment: I have edited my question please see it.If i do setSelectedIndex(-1).It is throwing NullPointerException.

Comment: `setSelectedIndex(-1)` is not a good idea. Use `0` instead as I posted in my answer.

Comment: I am calling Clear() function on combo_ActionPerformed event.I am retrieving value from combo as  int empid = Integer.parseInt(cmb_emp_id.getSelectedItem().toString()); for insertion query.n for clear() Iam doing as shown in my code.

Comment: Think about what happens with `Integer.parseInt(cmb_emp_id.getSelectedItem().toString());` when the selected value is `"Select Employee"`. What do you *want* `empid` to contain in this case?

Answer (score 5):

Try this method: [`setSelectedIndex(int anIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setSelectedIndex%28int%29)

> anIndex - an integer specifying the list item to select, where 0 specifies the first item in the list and -1 indicates no selection

Answer (score 2):

first of all you have to write your combo Box in an array,in order that you can call the number of index.

```
String[] array= { "name1","name2" };
    for (int i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
        comboBox.addItem(countries[i]);
```

then if you would like to reset the combo box you have to call the array again then use this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                                     //here you can give your combo the number of index
                comboBox.setSelected Index(0);
                comboBox.add Item(countries[i]);
            }
```